# How to parse email FROM headers with parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, email, parsing

I'm having trouble using the Python `email` module to parse emails where the FROM header has parentheses in it. This only seems to be the problem when using `email.policy.default` as opposed to `email.policy.compat32`.

Is there a solution to this problem, other than switching policies?

A minimum working example is below, for Python 3.6.5:

```python
import email
import email.policy as email_policy

raw_mime_msg=b"from: James Mishra \\(says hi\\) <james@example.com>"

compat32_obj = email.message_from_bytes(
    raw_mime_msg, policy=email_policy.compat32)

default_obj = email.message_from_bytes(
    raw_mime_msg, policy=email_policy.default)

print(compat32_obj['from'])
print(default_obj['from'])
```

The first print statement returns: 

`James Mishra \(says hi\) <james@example.com>`

and the second print statement returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1908, in get_address
    token, value = get_group(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1867, in get_group
    "display name but found '{}'".format(value))
email.errors.HeaderParseError: expected ':' at end of group display name but found '\(says hi\) <james@example.com>'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1734, in get_mailbox
    token, value = get_name_addr(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1720, in get_name_addr
    token, value = get_angle_addr(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1646, in get_angle_addr
    "expected angle-addr but found '{}'".format(value))
email.errors.HeaderParseError: expected angle-addr but found '\(says hi\) <james@example.com>'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_email.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(default_obj['from'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/message.py", line 391, in __getitem__
    return self.get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/message.py", line 471, in get
    return self.policy.header_fetch_parse(k, v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/policy.py", line 162, in header_fetch_parse
    return self.header_factory(name, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 589, in __call__
    return self[name](name, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 197, in __new__
    cls.parse(value, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 340, in parse
    kwds['parse_tree'] = address_list = cls.value_parser(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/headerregistry.py", line 331, in value_parser
    address_list, value = parser.get_address_list(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1931, in get_address_list
    token, value = get_address(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1911, in get_address
    token, value = get_mailbox(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1737, in get_mailbox
    token, value = get_addr_spec(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1583, in get_addr_spec
    token, value = get_local_part(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1413, in get_local_part
    obs_local_part, value = get_obs_local_part(str(local_part) + value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1454, in get_obs_local_part
    token, value = get_word(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/email/_header_value_parser.py", line 1340, in get_word
    if value[0]=='"':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: I don't think that header is valid according to the relevant RFCs. (I don't know about what the state of email looks like in practice, but by the RFCs, I don't think it's valid.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`email.policy.default` is intended to be compliant with the email RFCs, and your message is not compliant with [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). If the parenthesized part is supposed to be a comment, then the message should look like

```
raw_mime_msg=b"from: James Mishra (says hi) <james@example.com>"
```

to be compliant. If it is not supposed to be a comment, then the parentheses should appear inside a quoted string. That might look something like

```
raw_mime_msg=b'from: "James Mishra (says hi)" <james@example.com>'
```

---

Since your message is not compliant, using the policy that expects compliance is a poor fit. If you want to handle non-compliant messages, `email.policy.compat32` is a better choice than `email.policy.default`.

Comment: This is a message I received, not one I sent. I assumed the backslashes would make it compliant, but you're right that the quotes solve the problem.

Sounds like I'll just stick with `email.policy.compat32`.